# Выдаёт ArgumentOutOfRangeException вместо возвращаемого числа

Tags: c#, консоль

Я новичок, прошу тапками не кидаться.
проблемка возникла, что после вопроса о названии продукта вместо того , чтобы вернуть цену из каталога , он выдает default. Cовсем не знаю как это исправить. Надеюсь, что там нигде не опечаталась и заранее спасибо

```
public struct Goods
{
public string name;
public int cost;
public int amount;
}
public static int Katalog(ref Goods[] list, ref int MAX, ref int i)

 { 
  switch( list[i].name)

  {

case “milk”: return 10;
    case “cola”: return 7;
  // Дальше перечисление
     default: throw new ArgumetOutOfRangeException()
    }
 }

public static int Shop( ref Goods[] list)
{……
int MAX;
Console.WriteLine("сколько продуктов хотите купить?");
MAX=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i =1;i<=MAX;i++)

{
  try `
{

Console.WriteLine("напиши название продукта",i);
    list[i].name=Console.ReadLine();
    list[i].name=list[i].name.ToLower();

Goods [] listofGoods= new Goods[20];
list[i].cost= Katalog(ref listofGoods, ref MAX, ref i);
}
catch(ArgumentOutOfRanfeException)

{ Console.WriteLine("ERROR")
}
return list[i].cost


Console.WriteLine("напиши количество {0} товара", i);
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out list[i].amount))
      {
        Console.WriteLine("напиши количество {0} товара цифрой", i);
       }

......}

static void Main()
{//тут вызовем метод shop}
```

Comment: Покажите класс Goods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static int NameToPrice(string name)
{ 
  switch(name)
  {
    case "milk": return 10;
    case "cola": return 7;
    // Дальше перечисление
    default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
  }
}

public static int Shop( ref Goods[] list)
{
  ...
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
  {
    ...
    //Goods [] listofGoods= new Goods[20];
    list[i].cost = NameToPrice(list[i].name);
```

---

> Надеюсь, что там нигде не опечаталась

Опечатались. Вы что, *перепечатывали* код в вопрос?

---

```
public static int NameToPrice(string name)
{ 
  switch(name)
  {
    case "milk": return 10;
    case "cola": return 7;
    // Дальше перечисление
    default: return -1;
  }
}

public static int Shop( ref Goods[] list)
{
  ...
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
  {
    ...
    //Goods [] listofGoods= new Goods[20];
    list[i].cost = NameToPrice(list[i].name);
    if (list[i].cost == -1) {
      Console.WriteLine("No such product. Try again.");
      i--;
      continue;
    }
```

Comment: с int i я не опечаталась ,мне это нужно было чтобы потом он при первом вопросе показывал "1 продукт"

Comment: @Аля Ваш код не компилируется.

Comment: спасибо! помогло. не могли бы вы еще подсказать, как сделать, чтобы при неправильно введенном названии срабатывался default и снова задавался вопрос о названии, пока не будет правильно, потому что сейчас у меня переходит к вопросу о количестве даже при ошибке

Comment: @Аля Возвращайте `-1` из `NameToPrice`.